# Mapping a uni-directional 1:M

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a a uni-directional 1:M.

A User can have many Carts. Before getting into a debate about *ah this should be bidirectional*, just assume I have to make uni-directional.

```
class User {
}

class Cart {
    static belongsTo = [user: User]
    static mapping = {
         user joinTable: [name: 'cart_user']
    }
}
```

I get:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: user_id
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `static hasMany = [carts:Cart]`?

So try this (*uni-directional*):

```
class User {
    static hasMany = [carts:Cart]
}

class Cart {
     static belongsTo = [user: User]
}
```

**update:**
To make it *bidirectional*

```
class User {
        static hasMany = [carts:Cart]
    }

    class Cart {
         User user
         static belongsTo = [user: User]
    }
```

Comment: that make's the relationshiop bi-directional

Comment: Okay I forget about the bi-directional thing. I was focusing on the error. check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, but... it's bi-directional from Cart to the User as per question.

Comment: you dont have a handle of `user` in `cart` how is this bidirectional?

Comment: sorry. What I mean is, I don't want User to have a reference to Cart.  It is supposed to be unidirectional from Cart to User.

Comment: you dont want the `user.carts`?